# ASP.NET Core redirect from POST action to url doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I call a POST method in react but at the end I want to get redirected to the root url of my application.

I have this code where I'm trying to redirect to the root `url` (localhost:50000) , but it doesn't do anything

I also tried doing `Redirect("http://localhost:50000")` and it also doesn't work. I tried testing with google.com and I get a serverside error, basically I can't redirect to any website.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EntityBuilderController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public ActionResult CreateEntity(string xmlPath, string dllPath)
    {
        DataMapper.ExtractEntities(xmlPath, dllPath);

        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: after seeing the questioner original code through remote access I have found that questioner application is a ASP.NET Core React SPA.**

You cannot redirect from API controller to your client app view. You have to do the redirection from your client app on successful entity creation.

Comment: I tried, it doesnt redirect me anywhere. I dont understand why.

Comment: @davidbenalal have your tried `"/"` instead of `Url.Content("~/")`?

Comment: both answers still don't take me anywhere

Comment: doesnt work. I tried RedirectToRoute("/") and I get  POST 500 (Internal Server Error), do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185676/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-david-benalal).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure using `[ ]` instead of `{ }` in your route naming convention? Check it out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
//if you are replacing controller name then it should be
```

`[Route("api/{controller}")]`